# What mean the PHP documentation tags : #@+ and #@-

Tags: php, phpdoc

I found this in Zend Framework :

```
 /**#@+
 * @access protected
 */

/**
 * @var Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract
 * @static
 */
protected static $_defaultTransport = null;

...

/**#@-*/
```

Are these "open" and "close" tags ? Are they supported by phpdoc ?
I can't find any documentation about it (and it's not possible to google it)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That string defines a [docBlock template](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.docblocktemplate).

Comment: more detailed: it defines the block of similar structures with similar phpdoc descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

The "docblock template" is a set of tags that you want applied to all individual docblocks inside the template markers.  In your example above, it appears that you want the "@access protected" tag applied to all docblock'd elements inside the markers, starting with the $_defaultTransport element.

In short, it's a shortcut to avoid duplication.  In your example, you've saved yourself from duplicating "@access protected" across the docblocks of many class variables.